# Geometry problem with tangents to circle

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two points 3 cm apart.
>   (a)Let $P$ be any point not on $AB$ such that $PA$ =$2PB$. The tangent through $P$ to circle through $A,B,P$ meets $AB$ at $K$. Find $PK$ and $BK$

Here's a rough sketch I did

[Rough sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsxaP.jpg)

O is the center of circle through $A,B,P$

I know locus of P is a circle But I see no reason why K would be it's center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\triangle APK \sim \triangle PBK$ with ratio $2$, since $\angle BPK = \angle PAK$ by the Inscribed Angle Theorem. We have then

$$
\begin{align}
2PK &= 3+BK \\
\frac{PK}{BK} &= \frac{3+BK}{PK}
\end{align}
$$

By inspection, $PK=2, BK =1$.

Comment: They both have angle $K$ common but I don't see why any of the other two angles are equal?

Comment: Do you know the Inscribed Angle Theorem?

Comment: The one that means angles from same Chord to same segment of circle of equal, yes

Comment: It applies to tangents as well. Allow me to elaborate.

Comment: Are you talking about [Alternate segment theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?url=https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/&rct=j&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi65M_3_draAhWJQ48KHQxOBDUQFjAPegQIBhAB&q=inscribed+angle+therem+for+tangent&usg=AOvVaw1_Jel-eVV_rMTusAaRfM1Y)

Comment: That is a limiting case of the well known Inscribed Angle Theorem, same thing.